# Not able to add checkboxes to last column in dojo enhanced grid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I am creating the dojo Grid as below and I am using the indirectSelection plugin for creating a checkbox, as below, but by default the checkboxes will come at the first column of the grid.  How do I make it to come at the last column?

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'serialsGrid',
        style: 'width:auto;height:250px;',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px',
        plugins: {
            indirectSelection: {name:'Requested',headerSelector:true, width:"40px", styles:"text-align: center;"},
          pagination: {
              pageSizes: ["25", "50", "100", "All"],
              description: true,
              sizeSwitch: true,
              pageStepper: true,
              gotoButton: true,
                      /*page step to be displayed*/
              maxPageStep: 4,
                      /*position of the pagination bar*/
              position: "bottom"
          }
        }
    }, document.createElement('div'));

    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    //var temp=grid.domNode;
    dojo.byId("serialsGridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);
    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    serialsGridCopy=grid;
    grid.startup();
});
```

Comment: If you would like help, please edit the question and show the code for `layout`.  Thanks :)

Comment: var layout = [[
      {name: 'Line Number', field: 'bLineNumber'},                  
      {name: 'Product Number', field: 'dirProductNumber'},          
      {name: 'Number of Days', field: 'dirNumberOfDays'},           
      {name: 'Serial Received', field: 'bSerialReceived'},          
      {name: 'Receipt Date', field: 'bReceiptDate'},                
      {name: 'Serial Shipped', field: 'bSerialShipped'},            
      {name: 'Ship Date', field: 'bShipDate'},                      
      {name: 'Discrepant Serial',field : 'checkBox'}                
    ]];

Comment: layout is as above please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin itself has no capabilities of doing so as far as I know so I started looking at the functions the `EnhancedGrid` itself has and stumbled upon the function `moveColumn()` in `grid.layout`.
The documentation itself ([here](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/grid/_Layout)) was not really usefull, but I used it to move every column one position ahead so that the first column would become the last one.

I also made a working JSFiddle to demonstrate which you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pAGZd/3/). The code that is moving the columns can be found at the bottom of the code:

```
for (var i = 1;i < grid.layout.cells.length;i++) {
    grid.layout.moveColumn(1, 1, i, i-1, grid.layout);
}
```

What it does is the following: it moves every column starting from index 1, so that means all columns except the indirectSelection column one step ahead (`i-1`).

Comment: thanks Dimitri its working...                                         
if u dont mind i want one more thing,                                                                
I want to display name in the last coulmn which is having checkboxes, so i am putting name:'Requested',headerSelector:true,   in indirectSelection plugin but only headerselector checkbox is coming not the column name

Comment: I don't think you can have both the header selector and the name. So I think you should remove `headerSelector:true` from your properties.

Comment: @user2249287 Just like I expected (in my earlier comment) you can only choose between the checkbox **or** a name. I tried it in the JSFiddle and it worked. (see previous comment for more info)